# Android Annotations DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I'm trying to create DialogFragment with android annotations.

I have created dialogFragment class wint fragment annotation, but have no idea what next:

```
@EFragment
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public Date Value;

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year,month,day);
        Value = c.getTime();
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how to use this class and invoke fragment. Additionally i would like to grab Value after dialog closing.

Comment: You have to you the generated class `DatePickerFragment_`. Note the `_` suffix at the end. You can create an instance of the generated class with the builder: `DatePickerFragment_.builder().build();`. There is no dialog closing event handler in AndroidAnnotations, you have to use the plain-old Android methods for that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by WonderCsabo you should create dialogfragment, then you should use a FragmentTransaction to show it.

Below an example:

```
// create a FragmentTransaction from the FragmentManager
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Create and show the dialog.
DatePickerFragment dFrag = DatePickerFragment_.builder().build();
dFrag.show(ft, "dialog");
```